# Trying to use LUAJ in android app, can't find class Lua

Tags: android, eclipse, luaj

I suspect my ignorance is more profound than just LUAJ, so please be gentle.

GOAL: to run lua scripts periodically from within my app, passing data back and forth between Lua and Java, with a certain amount of security (don't let lua delete files, for example)

The majority of my app is straight android/java, and works fine.  I'm less of an idiot in that context.

Working from various examples, I finally got the LUAJ Jar file into Eclipse as an external Jar.  After that, these imports worked

```
import org.luaj.vm2.Lua;
import org.luaj.vm2.LuaClosure;
import org.luaj.vm2.LuaTable;
import org.luaj.vm2.LuaValue;
import org.luaj.vm2.Prototype;
import org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LuaC;
import org.luaj.vm2.lib.jse.CoerceJavaToLua;
import org.luaj.vm2.lib.jse.JsePlatform;
```

And most of the code is largely compiling, but I still have no "Lua" interface for use in this line here:

```
public class MyLuaEngine  implements Lua
```

That line fails with 'cannot implement since Lua is not a superclass'.  I'm pretty sure it has no idea what Lua is (unless it is finding a cognate in some other namespace or something).

Also, my overrides for Lua:add() etc complain as well (that there is no super for them to override)  For example:

```
@Override
public void run(int id, EventArgs args) throws LuaException
{
    LuaClosure script = scripts.get(id);
```

(must override a supertype)

I assume there is something like an external Jar that I need to add to Eclipse for Lua itself?, but I have found no instructions to do that (also, if LUAJ is a complete java implementation of Lua, then I would expect this interface class to be part of the LUAJ jar as well.

Of the three LUAJ jars I found, I only told Eclipse about one of them (JSE, not JME or Source).

Comment: I think I might have been reading more into the interface class used in the example than I should have.  It isn't strictly needed.  I made my own anyway and got past the compile issues.  Now I am just stuck on whether LuaClosure really does have a setfenv( LuaTable ) method or not  documettion here (http://luaj.sourceforge.net/api/2.0/org/luaj/vm2/LuaValue.html#setfenv(org.luaj.vm2.LuaValue)) says yes, but Eclipse says no.  Version diff I assume

Comment: here is the example I was inspired by.  I probably should have commented there instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471667/how-do-i-run-lua-scripts-on-android-in-a-java-application

Comment: OK, what I was missing was the fact that I was looking at examples and web pages from many different years, over which much had changed.  Once I found the top of the documentation tree for version 3.0, things started getting more deterministic.  After some other hassles, I was able to invoke lua from android, call specific functions, pass values in both directions, and let lua call out to special methods to access game state.  Wewt.

Answer (score 1):

So, here is what worked for me. using Luaj 3.0 and eclipse in an android java app.

1.) download the Luaj zip from its download page and make sure you get the jse jar into some known location (luaj-jse-3.0.jar)

2.) tell Eclipse to add it as an External Jar (right-click on project, buildPath/configureBuildPath/Libraries/Add External Jar

3.) add these imports

```
import org.luaj.vm2.Globals;
import org.luaj.vm2.LuaValue;
import org.luaj.vm2.lib.OneArgFunction;
import org.luaj.vm2.lib.TwoArgFunction;
import org.luaj.vm2.lib.jse.JsePlatform;
```

(and others as needed, but from those class paths.  Eclipse ctrl-shift-O figures it out so long as you have the jar file)

4.) Some Example Usage  (luaj sends print text to android logcat)

```
void testLua()
{
    //-----
    // Simple Test Lua Script

    String myScript = "require 'com.Your.Class.Path.Here.GameFunctions' \n" 
                    + " \n"
                    + "print 'hello, world from lua' \n" 
                    + "print( game.testFunction( 5 ) ) \n"
                    + " \n"
                    + "function foo() \n"
                    + "  print( 'You have been fooed!' ) \n"
                    + "end \n"
                    + " \n"
                    + "function foo2( a, b ) \n"
                    + "  print( 'Foo2 got '.. a ..', and '.. b ..' !' ) \n"
                    + "end \n"
                    + " \n"
                    + "function foo3( a, b ) \n"
                    + "  print( 'Foo3 got '.. a ..', and '.. b ..' !' ) \n"
                    + "  return 'fantastic!' \n"
                    + "end \n"
                    + " \n"
                    + "print 'Good bye from my lua program' \n"
                    + ""
                    ;
     // Create the globals object and initialize with standard stuff
    Globals globals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();

     // Load (and compile?) the simple script and get a Chunk
    LuaValue chunk = globals.load( myScript );

     // run the script once from the beginning (root level)
    chunk.call();

     // run it a second time, just to see if it blows up, and
     // get the return value, if any. (didnt blow up)
    LuaValue result = chunk.call();

    // try to call a specific function, no args
    LuaValue foo = globals.get( "foo" );    // get the function to call as a LuaValue
    if( !foo.isnil() ) {
        foo.call();   // runs just that function
    }

    LuaValue foo2 = globals.get( "foo2" );  // pass two args
    if( !foo2.isnil() ) {
        foo2.call(  LuaValue.valueOf("first"), 
                    LuaValue.valueOf("second") );
    }

    LuaValue foo3 = globals.get( "foo3" );  // pass 2 args, get 1 back
    if( !foo3.isnil() ) {
        LuaValue retVal = foo3.call(    LuaValue.valueOf("first"), 
                                        LuaValue.valueOf("second") );
        Log.v( TAG, "LUA: foo3 returned: " + retVal.toString() );
    }
```

}

The first line of the lua script is a require command calling out the full class path to a public class I called GameFunctions.  It is the interface by which lua can call back out to custom java functions of interest (getting a player's score, perhaps.  Playing a sound effect, etc)

My Bare Bones implementation looks like this:  (and many thanks to all the web pages that contributed to this, though ultimately I just guessed that a 2 arg call would have modName and env)

When you .load() the Script String, it is compiled and the return LuaValue (chunk) is the compiled code.  but you can't .get( "functionName" ) on the chunk, you have to use the 'globals' object instead (which makes sense, but spins my head a little wrt the just in time compilation, which I feel takes place in ,load() but I guess leaves behind some sort of symbol table for globals to use later.

ANYWAY, so this class is instantiated the moment the .call() command executes the script and gets to the 'require'  After calling the do-nothing creator, Luaj invokes the 2 arg methof with the modName and env.  You can then stick anything you want into the environment.  In this case, we build a LuaTable of functions and then stick that into the environment under the name "game" and then from lua we can invoke Java game functions like

whatever = game.doSomething( some, junk )

Though you probably want to put all the lua in a separate thread so your UI doesn't stall.  I am hoping the Lua debugging hooks exist somewhere so I can limit execution times for player-provided infinite loops :-)

```
public class GameFunctions extends TwoArgFunction {
private static final String TAG = GameFunctions.class.getSimpleName();

public GameFunctions() {
}

public LuaValue call( LuaValue modname, LuaValue env ) 
{
    Log.v( TAG, "LUA: modName: " + modname.toString() 
            + ", Env: " + env.toString() );

    LuaTable game = new LuaTable(); 

    // the actual functions get added to game table
    game.set("testFunction", new testFunction());

    // we set it into the environment so lua can see them
    env.set("game", game);

    // we mark it so no 'require' is needed 
    env.get("package").get("loaded").set("game", game);

    return game;
}

// An example Game Function... not a very good one.  Pretend
// it plays a sound effect.  I just wanted to test arg passing
// don't forget to convert to LuaValues as needed.

class testFunction extends OneArgFunction {
    public LuaValue call(LuaValue x) {
        return LuaValue.valueOf( "you said: " + x );
    }
}
```

}

In theory, the bit at the end is supposed to make it unnecessary to include the require command in the script.  I hope that's true, but I don't really mind the require in my application

IN any case, I hope this helps someone else someday.  This was all true enough in March 2015 as of luaj version 3.0,  only the future knows how misleading this will all turn out to be later.